# Incorrect print statement for username/password program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def login():
    UserName = input("Please enter your username: ")
    passw = input("Please enter your password: ")
    check(UserName, passw)
    if check(UserName, passw) == True:
        print("Thank you for logging in. Please enjoy these lyrics")
    else:
        print("Sorry, either your username or password is incorrect")

def check(UserName, passw):
    pword = {}
    for line in open('unames_passwords.txt','r'):
        user, password = line.split()
        pword[user] = password
        if user == UserName and password == passw:
            return True
        else:
            return False


def main():
    login()
```

The issue I'm having with my current code is, it prints the if True, print statement only if I enter the first name and password that is contained in a file, but if I enter any other name and password within the same file, it always prints the statement issued under else. Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return from `check()` based solely on the *first line* of the password file. If the first password does not match, you return `False` immediately.

Move `return False` *out* of the loop, so that it is only executed when you have scanned the whole file:

```
def check(UserName, passw):
    for line in open('unames_passwords.txt','r'):
        user, password = line.split()
        if user == UserName and password == passw:
            return True

    return False
```

I removed the `pword` dictionary handling here; your code doesn't actually make use of it.

You *probably* want to avoid calling `check()` twice every login, and you don't have to test for `== True`; the `if` statement *already* tests that for you:

```
def login():
    UserName = input("Please enter your username: ")
    passw = input("Please enter your password: ")
    if check(UserName, passw):
        print("Thank you for logging in. Please enjoy these lyrics")
    else:
        print("Sorry, either your username or password is incorrect")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Took me a moment to realize why it was suppose to be done that way. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

the else statement returns false, which means it exits the function on the first failed comparison.

What you need to do is simply have the if, and at the end of the for if there's no return true, return false.

So like:

```
for line in open('unames_passwords.txt','r'):
        user, password = line.split()
        pword[user] = password
        if user == UserName and password == passw:
            return True
return False
```